# Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Quota Exceeded)

Tags: azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've made a chatbot on language studio and i connected it with bot framework composer through keys and endpoints, it worked correct! Then i published the project from bot framework composer to azure , wrote an html code(the below one) and connected the project with the html code through the secret key from the direct line. At first it run correctly but after a few days checking how it works i have this error : Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Quota Exceeded).

*I have a free student account on azure*

After this error when i try to make any changes or test the project it appears a similar error:    403:Out of call volume quota for TextAnalytics F0 pricing tier. Please retry after 9 days. To increase your call volume switch to a paid tier.

Questions:

1)How can i solve the error? Is the only solution to pay?

2)After the html code runs correctly can i import it to an existing site? How? Will there be any problem cause the project runs on the cloud?

Comment: this is the scrict on the html<script>
      (async function() {
        const res = await fetch('https://webchat-mockbot.azurewebsites.net/directline/token', { method: 'POST' });
        const { token } = await res.json();

        window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
          {
            directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret:'TUL_wEGMbz8.8QaygLhYnhIkmvEUvuFhdnKEcIj-p3vlUAHFDPYbuOU' })
          },
          document.getElementById('webchat')
        );

        document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
      })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Code is unreadable in comments.